# Create a new variable in flat tables based on existing column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sum, jupyter

I have got the following dataframe:

```
lst=[['01012021','A',5],['01012021','B',-10],['01012021','C',20],['01022021','A',20],['01022021','B',-30],['01022021','C',40]]
df2=pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['Date','Art','AuM'])
```

I would like to create in column Art a new variable (D)  by adding A, B and C. It should be grouped by the columns date and Art. The result looks like this:

```
lst=[['01012021','A',5],['01012021','B',-10],['01012021','C',20],['01012021','D',15],['01022021','A',20],['01022021','B',-30],['01022021','C',40],['01022021','D',30]]
df2=pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['Date','Art','AuM'])
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) `Date`, [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) `'D'` as a new column `Art` to the result and [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to the orginal dataframe:

```
df2.append(df2.groupby('Date', as_index=False).AuM.sum().assign(Art='D'))
```

If needed, you can sort by appending `.sort_values(['Date', 'Art'])`:

```
       Date Art  AuM
0  01012021   A    5
1  01012021   B  -10
2  01012021   C   20
0  01012021   D   15
3  01022021   A   20
4  01022021   B  -30
5  01022021   C   40
1  01022021   D   30
```